# ifort compiler not found by CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, fortran, gitlab-ci, intel-fortran

I'm using GitlabCI to perform some tests on a software library, which is supposed to provide multiplatform support. The compilation is performed by CMake, which is also supposed  to detect compilers automatically. The problem is, that it's not able to detect `ifort` even when it's directly in the `PATH`.

My `CMake` version is `3.16.0-rc3`.

#### .gitlab-ci.yml

```
win_visual_studio_2017_static_manual:
    tags:
        - Win

    image: windows:latest

    stage: build

    variables:
        DEPENDENCIES_LINK_TYPE: 'static'

    before_script:
        - 'rmdir /s /q build external_dependencies\*'
        - 'call VsDevCmd.bat &&
           call "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\bin\psxevars.bat" intel64 vs2017 &&
           copy /b NUL prep_success'

    artifacts:
        paths:
            - 'prep_success'
        expire_in: 5 mins

    script:
        - 'if not exist prep_success ( exit 1 )'
        - 'where cl'
        - 'where ifort'
        - 'echo %cd%'
        - 'echo %PATH%'
        - 'call build_scripts\windows\win_VS_build_x64_release.bat'
```

#### Output

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
  on win-ci1 Kh9rrkTg
Using Shell executor...
Running on WIN-CI1...
Fetching changes...
Removing prep_success
HEAD is now at 6008f3c [FIX] [WIN] Trying to fix CI on Windows
From https://code.it4i.cz/bes0030/mylib
   6008f3c..58c3907  dev        -> origin/dev
Checking out 58c3907d as dev...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ rmdir /s /q build external_dependencies\*
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
$ call VsDevCmd.bat && call "C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\bin\psxevars.bat" intel64 vs2017 && copy /b NUL prep_success
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
Intel(R) Parallel Studio XE 2019 Update 5
Copyright (C) 2009-2019 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.

Intel(R) Compiler 19.0 Update 5 (package 281)

        1 file(s) copied.
$ if not exist prep_success ( exit 1 )
$ where cl
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe
$ where ifort
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe
$ echo %cd%
C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\Kh9rrkTg\0\bes0030\mylib
$ echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\bin\intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\;C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\Kh9rrkTg\0\bes0030\mylib\..\..\intel64\libfabric\bin\utils;C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\Kh9rrkTg\0\bes0030\mylib\..\..\intel64\libfabric\bin;C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\Kh9rrkTg\0\bes0030\mylib\..\..\intel64\bin\release;C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\Kh9rrkTg\0\bes0030\mylib\..\..\intel64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\ipp\..\redist\intel64\ipp;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\redist\intel64_win\mkl;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\tbb\bin\..\..\redist\intel64\tbb\vc_mt;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.068\compilers_and_libraries_2019\windows\tbb\bin\..\..\redist\intel64\tbb\vc_mt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\\MSBuild\15.0\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja
$ call build_scripts\windows\win_VS_build_x64_release.bat
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 to target Windows 10.0.14393.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26726.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.15.26726.0
-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Gitlab-Runner/builds/Kh9rrkTg/0/bes0030/mylib/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Gitlab-Runner/builds/Kh9rrkTg/0/bes0030/mylib/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.166+gd4e8d81a88 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

As you can see, `where ifort` provides the path to `ifort` compiler, also `PATH` variable contains the same one in the very beginning. Still, CMake doesn't seem to detect the compiler. **What can be wrong here? I don't want to specify the path to the compiler explicitly, if possible.**

Comment: If ifort is to be visible in a new shell, you must invoke the compilervars.bat script again to set up C++ and Fortran.

Comment: Set the environment variable `FC` (for Fortran compiler). In windows: `set FC=ifort`. If the environement is set, the full path is not necessary.